# ArcGIS importing from file geodatabase A to B without stopping service

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, esri-geodatabase

I have file geodatabase B which is use by arcgis server as a data store

and on a schedule interval I need to import new data from file geodatabase A.

geodatabase need to be wiped and accept the data from geodatabase A.

May i know if there is a arcgis tool for this?

This process must not stop the arcgis server/services